# Let $x$ be an element of order $2261$ in a group $G$. How many distinct subgroups of $G$ are contained in ⟨$x$⟩?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What I have figured out so far:

Number of subgroups of $⟨x⟩$ could be $1, 7, 17, 19, 119, 133, 323$ or $2261$

$x^{2261} = Id$

This question has left me drawing at a complete blank. Any pointers?

Also I must add, G is not necessarily finite, Abelian, or cyclic.

Comment: Hint: $2261=7\cdot17\cdot19$ and Cauchy theorem

Comment: @NombreFalso123 sorry I still don't see it. I guess it's because I never studied Cauchy theorem.

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}/2261\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Put the Sylow theorems to use, for every prime $p^n$ that divides 2261, there exists at least one subgroup of order $p^n.$  etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\langle x\rangle$ is a cyclic group, so we are looking at [subgroups of a cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups).

For example $\langle x^7\rangle$ generates a group of size $323$. For every element $y=x^k$ where $k$ is coprime to $2261$, $\langle y^7\rangle$ is the same group. This is the only subgroup of $\langle x\rangle$ of size $323$.

Similarly the other size subgroups of $\langle x\rangle$ are unique per size. So we have one subgroup each of size each of the factors of $2261$, so $\fbox{$8$ }$ subgroups in total, including the identity alone (size $1$) and the full $\langle x\rangle$ (size($2261$).

Comment: Using this logic, the answer I obtain is 575, which is incorrect. I added 323, 133, and 119 together since each of these numbers is associated with a prime whose product gives 2261

Comment: Didn't know this was the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups. Thanks for your help!